# It seems that more than three tasks per container instance cannot be placed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have 10 service/task definitions each of which requires 512 memory and 10 cpu (from container definition).
I have three t2.medium instances each of which has 4GB memory.
So it should be no problem to launch up to 24 task instances.

However those three instances run maximum only 7 services (3/2/2).
For the services that are not running in "events" tab there are following errors:

**service integrityCheck was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching container-instance 3e2dbe6a-7a07-46f2-846b-ccccb9adaeee encountered error "RESOURCE:ENI".**

I tried updating AMI on ec2 instances to latest ecs-optimized but it did not help. It seems that one ec2/container instance can't start more than 3 tasks? Strange thing is that it worked fine like 1 month ago (all 10 services were running) and those errors appeared ~20-26 days ago.

Any idea?

Each service uses awsvpc network mode and awslog log driver.

---

Here are my network interfaces listed:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The message "RESOURCE:ENI" indicates that it's a problem with allocating an elastic network interface.

Per the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI), a `t2.medium` should be able to allocate 3 ENIs. So, assuming that ECS assigns a distinct ENI to each container, that would be the reason that you can't assign more than three containers to an instance.

But you're indicating that you're actually limited to 2 containers per instance. Which makes me wonder if you're somehow exceeding the [limit of ENIs per region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html#vpc-limits-enis). That shouldn't happen unless ENIs are being detached and not removed (which could possibly happen if your IAM permissions aren't correct). I recommend looking at the ENI page in the AWS Console to make sure that you don't have a lot of unattached ENIs.

Comment: Updated my question with a screenshot of network interfaces. Anything suspicious? How I can tell which network interfaces are not being used?

Comment: one container is used by ecs agent. that basically means you can effectively use 1 ENI less than specified. as per the new updates to limits in the answer above, i think its best to use c5.large (10 ENI) or some type of new "a" type instances. Also, to enable ENI trunking check everything specified here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-eni.html#eni-trunking-launching

Comment: Is there a fix for this? I've a few `t2.small` instances, and this limit is blocking.

Also, having two services means that I can't roll updates, since a next-version container can never be deployed unless I've a standby instance.

Answer (score 8):

For those still having this issue, a fix was released in June 2019 to enable ENI trunking. E.g. with ENI trunking enabled, a c5.xlarge that used to be limited to 3 tasks now can support 20.

Have a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-instance-eni.html

Comment: Also, current EC2-task limits per ECS instance can be found there. Very useful, thanks!